# Open port on CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I want to change my SSH port on CentOS.

But first I want to make sure the port is open before doing this.

Since SSH is the only way for me to access the server and I don't want to lock myself out :-)

I've used the following two commands to add an iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

After that I've tested it with the following command:

```
nmap -v -sV localhost -p 4444
```

With the following result:

```
Host localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) appears to be up ... good.
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):
PORT     STATE  SERVICE VERSION
4444/tcp closed unknown
```

The state is `closed` so it looks like I haven't properly opened the port.

What should I do to open the port?

Comment: Have you restart your iptables service?

Comment: Did you already change the port sshd listens on? If there's nothing listening on port 4444 it will appear closed to nmap.

Comment: @garconcn: I haven't restarted iptables. Is it needed?

Comment: @mikkoko: are you sure about that? If I change the port of SSH and the iptables isn't yet properly set I lock myself out with no way of accessing the server.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/116488/safely-changing-iptables-firewall-rules

Comment: let's get the current rule set - can you run "service iptables status" and then paste the output?

Comment: for future, you can just make ssh listen on both ports while making sure iptables is setup right on the new port. Just have two Port lines in the config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iptables command you used is right.  Check netstat -anlp | grep 4444 to see if anything has that port open.  My guess is your sshd is not listening on 4444 yet.  Make sure if you've added 4444 to the sshd_config, that you've restarted sshd as well for the change to take effect.

Comment: is there a way to check if the port is already open before changing SSH port? Or are you sure I've correctly setup my iptables. Should I restart iptables as garconcn suggested? Thanks in advance!

Comment: By running that "iptables -I INPUT" command, you have added the rule to the top of your input ruleset.  There's no "reloading" of iptables required, it's an instant change.  And yes, I am absolutely sure that the command you ran will open TCP port 4444 inbound to the server in question.

Comment: netcat might help you test it (have it listen to the port, then connect to that port from another machine and see if you get the connection.) That way you don't lock yourself out. https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/299815-ncat-the-network-swiss-army-knife-

Answer (score 1):

Changing the port will not increase the security. You should disable in sshd_conf: root login authentication and password authentication. Use only ssh key based authentication.

To test your new port to see if it is reachable use `netcat`. Run: `nc -l 4444` or `netcat -l 4444` on the server, then test with `nmap` from the workstation.

Comment: `Changing the port will not increase the security. You should disable in sshd_conf: root login authentication and password authentication. Use only ssh key based authentication.` I know :) just want to keep my logs clean(er)

Comment: Changing the port does block out scripts and scans to standard ports. Denyhost can help block traffic too. It won't stop a targeted attack but it does make casual kiddies move along.

Comment: +1 for Denyhost. Great tool.